# Setting a dynamic page title with php not working?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I am trying to set a dynamic page title for my one of my pages but it seems to not be working. I use phpMyAdmin and I have the same code that is dynamic for another page that grabs a server name. I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. 
Here is my my current code: URL looks like this http://test.com/index.php?category=test

```
switch ($pageTitle) {
case 'index.php':
    if(isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id'])){
        $id = (INT)$_GET['id'];
        $query = $database->query("SELECT `name` FROM `categories` WHERE `category_id` = '$id'");
        $fetch = $query->fetch_assoc();
        $pageTitle = $fetch['name'];
    } else {
    $pageTitle = "test title";
    $description = "test desc";
    }
    break;
```

Here is another code snippet that works and uses a server name: URL looks like this http://test.com/server.php?id=#

```
case 'server.php':
    if(isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id'])){
        $id = (INT)$_GET['id'];
        $query = $database->query("SELECT `name` FROM `servers` WHERE `id` = '$id'");
        $fetch = $query->fetch_assoc();
        $pageTitle = $fetch['name'];

    } else {
        $pageTitle = "Server Details";
    }
    break;
```

Anyone know why I cannot get the name of the category?

Comment: I personally think your server is trying to tell that you are not supposed to insert raw input right into your SQL statement...in all seriousness, side note, don't do this: `"SELECT `name` FROM `categories` WHERE `category_id` = '$id'"` You need to bind parameters/values here. This is an sql injection waiting to happen. Don't rely on `(INT)$_GET['id']` to sanitize, I would just get in the habit of parameterizing.

Comment: Have you checked for any sql errors?

Comment: Another side note, you only need `if(!empty($_GET['id']))`, `isset()` is not necessary when you use `empty()`

Comment: Also, try doing just `"SELECT \`name\` FROM \`categories\``, if it pulls all the rows, then do the `where` with a hardcoded number that you know exists (not a variable) and see if it pulls. Then you should be able to narrow down from there.

Comment: @Rasclatt How would I change the code to prevent an  sql injection attack?

Comment: @RasclattI tried the `SELECT name FROM categories` and still did not work. The only difference between the code above that is working is the server name code uses an id in the URL and the category code uses a string in the URL like this test.com/index.php?category=test

Comment: What about just `SELECT * FROM categories`? Does that pull data?

Comment: @Rasclatt I just tried `SELECT * FROM categories` and had no luck. How would I make it so it uses a string instead of an id because in the URL it is like this index.php?category=test. That might be the problem there.

Comment: Well if you can't even get such a general selection to work, are you sure you are not getting errors? Are you sure that you have data in that table?

Comment: @Rasclatt I am not getting any errors at all on the webpage or in the file. I have two columns in the table "name" and "category_id" which has like 20 records stored currently. It just defaults to the else page title.

Comment: This is `mysqli_*` right? Isn't there a `mysqli_error()` function to check errors from mysql?

Comment: Yeah it is using mysqli. There is that function but I think you have to set it to equal a value or else it displays the error.

Comment: Did you try getting results from `mysqli_error()`?

Comment: I am not exactly sure how to setup the mysqli_error with this code